# Send multiple emails using smtpclient.send - not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, smtp, smtpclient

The code below works when using on local machine, but fails when published on server (HostGator) for multiple emails in to. It also works if I am trying to send email to just one person.

```
 public void SendMailToMultiples(MailAddress fromAddress, string fromPassword, MailAddressCollection toAddress, string subject, string body)
       {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(){
            Subject = subject,
            IsBodyHtml = true,
            Body = body,
            From = fromAddress
        };

        foreach(var email in toAddress)
        {
            message.To.Add(email.Address);
        }

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = HOST_NAME,
            Port = PORT_NUMBER,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
        };

        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: if it fails it should produce an error; either an exception (if the failure is immediate) or a bounce message to the "From" address (if the failure is delayed). What is the error?

Comment: Multiple email? or one email to more than one recipient?

Comment: @Michael I do not get any error. Works fine on localhost, and on publishing to server, I do not get any error. Just no mails.

Comment: @Kashif yes, one email to more than one recepient (max 5 in this case)

Comment: implementing the same method for one email address, works fine

Comment: If you're getting no error, then SmtpClient is succeeding.  the SMTP server is failing to send or relay the message.  Ensure you have the correct SMTP credentials for what you want to do and that it is configured property.

Comment: The mail server may prevent sending to multiple recipients, as an anti-spam measure. Try sending the email to 1 recipient at a time, i.e. loop over the addresses in the MailAddressCollection.

Comment: @PeterRitchie I am using the same SMTP configuration on my localhost env and it works fine there.

Comment: @antmx does not work for even single email, iterated over a loop. Only works for single email, single instance. Really lost :(

Comment: @amitm30 Some SMTP configuration on a different server isn't guarenteed to work the same.  That server may not have access to the same mail servers, could be one a SPAM list, etc.  I suggest testing sending mail from that server using some other piece of software--if that doesn't work either, you know it's not your code.

Comment: @PeterRitchie good idea. let me try and put a simple application up on the server, and test for exceptions. Longer process, but should resolve the issue for me